# Issue "removing" a block of lines from a .sql file

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working on a script that will remove a block of lines from a SQL dump (basically, cleanse any table we do not want to restore). I thought I had it working, but when trying to restore the resulting file to my database I realized that when the script rewrites to the file, it's missing more lines than it should, and the restore fails. Here's my paltry attempt at this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

to_keep = []
to_remove = []

f = open("backuptest.sql","r")
lines = f.readlines()

f.close()

### Function to remove lines associated with a table block
def remove_lines(table_name):
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if "structure" in line and table_name in line:
            for j in range(i, len(lines)):
                to_remove.append(lines[j])
                if "UNLOCK TABLES;" in lines[j]:
                    break
        if line not in to_remove:
            to_keep.append(line)
            f.write(line)

print "Finding lines"

f = open("backuptest.sql", "w")
remove_lines("advanced_searches")
f.close()

f = open("backuptest.sql", "w")
remove_lines("test_table2")
f.close()

f = open("backuptest.sql", "w")
remove_lines("test_table3")
f.close()
```

And here's what one of the blocks of the sql file looks like, for reference:

```
-- Table structure for table `advanced_searches`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `advanced_searches`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `advanced_searches` (
  `batch_size` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `advanced_searches`
--

LOCK TABLES `advanced_searches` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `advanced_searches` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `advanced_searches` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I start the script by matching against the first line in such a block (includes the word "structure" and the table name), then I'm attempting to iterate from that line through "UNLOCK TABLES;" What's happening instead is it's removing ALL instances of "UNLOCK TABLES;" in the script, even from blocks I do not want removed, and it's also removing the following line from each block as well " ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; " (The closing parentheses through the rest of that line).

Thanks for any help. I'll keep plugging away at what I've missed.

Comment: from your example input what exactly do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1):

## Try `sqlparse`

```
$ pip install sqlparse
```

Quick test from tutorial:

```
>>> import sqlparse
>>> sql = "select * from foo; select * from bar;"
>>> res = sqlparse.split(sql)
>>> res
[u'select * from foo;', u'select * from bar;']
```

Applying to your SQL script:

```
>>> sql = """-- Table structure for table `advanced_searches`
... --
... 
... DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `advanced_searches`;
... /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
... /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
... CREATE TABLE `advanced_searches` (
...   `batch_size` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
... ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
... /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
... 
... --
... -- Dumping data for table `advanced_searches`
... --
... 
... LOCK TABLES `advanced_searches` WRITE;
... /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `advanced_searches` DISABLE KEYS */;
... /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `advanced_searches` ENABLE KEYS */;
... UNLOCK TABLES;"""
...
>>> res = sqlparse.split(sql)
>>> res
[u'-- Table structure for table `advanced_searches`\n--\n\nDROP TABLE IF EXISTS `advanced_searches`;',
 u'/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;',
 u'/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;',
 u"CREATE TABLE `advanced_searches` (\n  `batch_size` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'\n) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;",
 u'/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;',
 u'--\n-- Dumping data for table `advanced_searches`\n--\n\nLOCK TABLES `advanced_searches` WRITE;',
 u'/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `advanced_searches` DISABLE KEYS */;',
 u'/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `advanced_searches` ENABLE KEYS */;',
 u'UNLOCK TABLES;']
```

This provides properly parsed script and last thing to do, is to filter it one by one, picking only those, which seem to be needed. This I leave to you.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to use a global variable in place of a function argument - using an argument makes the "coupling" between the function and its environment much clearer. Since you want to remove several tables from a single file then it's probably best to start by reading all the lines in, then passing the output lines back as a new result.

```
def remove_lines(lines, table_name):
   output_lines = []
   for line in lines:
       if line.startswith("-- structure for table") and table_name in line:
           while "UNLOCK TABLE" not in line:
               line = lines.next()
       else:
           output_lines.append(line)
   return output_lines
```

This function should be called with a set of lines and a table_name, and it returns a list of lines which can be further processed if necessary. The final set can then be used to overwrite the original file (are you SURE you don't want to keep backups?) like this:

```
with open("backuptest.sql","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for table_name in ("advanced_searches", "test_table2", "test_table1"):
    lines = removelines(lines, table_name)
with open("backuptest.sql", "w") as f
    f.writelines(lines)
```